# Convert Latex to odt using tex4ht

Tags: conversion, tex4ht, open-office

Based on advice from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format) I'm trying to use [tex4ht](http://tug.org/tex4ht/) to convert a latex document into something readable by MS Word. I was planning to use tex4ht to convert `.tex` to `odt` format.

I'm running into problems though. I'm using a mac, and have TeXShop installed. I ran the line:

```
mk4ht oolatex myfile.tex
```

but I then got the message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `preamble.tex' not found.
```

The file `preamble.tex` does exist in my main document; I linked the file by using the line `\input{preamble}` in `myfile.tex`. As `myfile.tex` is very large I want to use a lot of `input{}` commands.

Is there a different command (or approach) that I can take to convert this file?

Just to clarify, I also ran the command in the form `htlatex myfile.tex` which resulted in the same error message.

Comment: Is your .tex file in the same folder mk4ht resides?

Comment: no - `mk4ht` is where `TexShop` installed it; I'm not sure where that location is.

Comment: just to clarify, I simplified my file path for the question. `myfile.tex` is actually `/username/Docs/Article/myfile.tex`

Comment: You could run a script before running latex like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879021/finding-a-line-in-a-text-file-and-replacing-it-with-the-contents-of-an-existing) to find and replace all \input lines with the contents of the file.

Comment: try mk4ht oolatex ~/Docs/Article/myfile.tex  assuming that /username is your own directory.

Comment: Just to confirm - are myfile.tex and preamble.tex in the same folder? Because `htlatex myfile` and `mk4ht oolatex myfile` work for me just fine (Macbook Pro running TeXLive 2011).

Comment: Yes - myfile.tex and preamble.tex are in the same folder. I'll try testing this out with a complete file to check if I have the same problem.