# Is there a way to convert latex to msword?

Tags: msword, word-to-latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)

Is there a way to convert a full latex file to the Microsoft Word readable format?

Yes, I hate word too, but unfortunally my monograph was recused becuase is out of the university rules and I need urgently put it in this format.

Unfortunally, copy and past all text is very hard because it has several formulas.

Anyone knows a good way to solve this? Or in particular, anyone know how to convert a latex formart to msword format?

I will try convert a pdf to word, but I don't know I can use this well. If someone have a idea I would like to know.

Appreciate the help, thx.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format

Comment: Also consider [`tex2word`](http://www.chikrii.com/products/tex2word/tex-to-word/).

Comment: Thx guys. I will take a look.