# Is there a way to export XeLaTeX document into doc or similar?

Tags: xetex

I need to export my `.tex` file to .doc. I tried to do it using

```
mk4ht ooxelatex file.tex
```

but got complete garbage as output. The file itself is quite simple - some text and a pair of images.

Is there a way to do it?

EDIT:

[small example file](http://pastie.org/3839034)

Comment: [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) should convert LaTeX to .docx — haven't tried it though.

Comment: @slhck - it does not work with xelatex :(

Comment: It will be very difficult to help you without knowing the document.  TeX4ht has the capability to convert to OpenOffice format.  It isn't guaranteed to work, but the reasons why it doesn't work can be complicated so without a sample document it's hard to help you further.

Comment: @AndrewStacey - I added the example document.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this related question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41306/9632)

Comment: @Sveinung: Good tip. It's even more comfortable for everyone if you just paste the plain link. It will automatically be truncated and the question title will appear as a mouseover tooltip, hence users can see the question without having to click the link.

Comment: @slhck just tried pandoc, and it seems to be complaining about a lot of my LaTeX code!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason  why compilation of your document fails is probably that `tex4ht` has some problems with `xetex` and `fontspec`, it is best to use `pdftex` or `luatex` as engines for use with `tex4ht`.

Best option for `xelatex` documents is to have some switch in the preamble, so you don't load problematic packages when you compile the document with `tex4ht`

Your sample document corrected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

% NOTES
% Organization?
% Citations in text?

\makeatletter
\newcommand\compparbox[2]{%
\parbox{\dimexpr #1\relax}{#2}
}
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
 \usepackage[russian]{babel} % for russian hypenation
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
}{

  % TEMPORARY - remove in final version!
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{10em}

  \usepackage{xltxtra}
  \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

  \usepackage[russian]{babel} % for russian hypenation
  \usepackage[top=20mm, bottom=20mm, left=25mm, right=25mm]{geometry}

  \pagestyle{empty} % remove page numbering


}
 \usepackage{setspace}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \setlist{nolistsep} % denser list
 \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\singlespacing

  \begin{center}

    \large
    Заголовок
    \vspace{1em}

    \normalsize
    Автор \href{mailto:someone@somewhe.re}{\nolinkurl{<someone@somewhe.re>}} (Россия, Москва)

  \end{center}

Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста
Много текста

  \vspace{2em}
  \noindent
  \compparbox{\textwidth/2 - 0.8em}{
    \phantomsection
    \label{comp1}
    %\includegraphics[width=\textwidth/2 - 0.8em]{comp1-mne.png}
    Рис.1. Картирование ``сенсорного''\\ компонента.
  }
  \hspace{1em}
  \compparbox{\textwidth/2 - 0.8em}{
    \phantomsection
    \label{comp4}
  %  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth/2 - 0.8em]{comp4-mne.png}
    Рис.2. Картирование ``моторного'' \\ компонента.
  }  

  \vspace{2em}
  \subsection*{Список литературы}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \phantomsection \label{ikeda1992}
          Ikeda A., L\"{u}ders H., Burgess R., Shibasaki H. 1992. Movement-related potentials recorded 
          from supplementary motor area and primary motor area. Brain. V. 115. pp 1017-1043.
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

with `\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}` you can decide which package to load or not to load, when `tex4ht` is running. As first parameter include packages for use with `tex4ht`, as second packages for `xelatex`.

Compile with

```
mk4ht oolatex sample.tex "xhtml, charset=utf-8"
```

Note: Your parboxes are incorrectly transformed with `tex4ht`, I think you will need some custom configuration to get it working. But this needs some knowledge of `odt` xml structure

Comment: I added the sample document to the question.

Comment: I almost got it to work, using your advice - the only problem left is the `\parbox`. What package should I import so the converter would recognize it?

Comment: Those parboxes compile just fine for me, maybe it is a version difference?

Comment: I would be just fine with the way they are outputted right now (just two big images one after another), but with the garbage (/2 - 0.8em/2 - 0.8em/2 - 0.8e) removed. Maybe I can define something like you defined in "compparbox", which would just silence it?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\parbox}[2]{ #2 }` still achieves the same effect - first argument is still printed for some reason.

Comment: Strange thing is that if I define that macro in the normal xelatex run, everything works as expected.

Comment: Ok, that much of clean-up I can certainly survive :) Thank you!