# Tex2Word plugin for Microsoft Word

Tags: conversion, tools, msword, spelling, grammar

Is there any TeX to Word plugin to be added for free in Microsoft Word?

The main reason behind this is that I want to use the easy to use grammar checker of Microsoft Word after writing my article in LyX/LaTeX.

I know there are some grammar checker in LaTeX. But they list a long and non-important grammatical errors which takes a lot of time to change. Instead, Word shows it in a more user-friendly way.

Comment: Is the purpose to have the final document in Word format? If not, you could first write your document in Word (without taking care of formatting, just plain text), grammar-check it in Word, and then copy the text into LyX, and finally do the final formatting.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format

Comment: Yes. You are right. I was just wondering if there is any package for doing the tex2word convertion. I can also convert it to .odt file then convert that format to docx :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use TeX4ht to convert it to ODF. The command is thus:

```
htlatex filename "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-coo -cvalidate"
```

See the documentation of TeX4ht here:
http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html#QQ1-9-38

Then you can use any ODF-compatible word processor (LibreOffice, OpenOffice, and even MsWord) to convert it to .doc or .docx.