# From .tex to .doc format. Is it possible?

Tags: conversion, msword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)

sorry, this can be a stupid question... My teacher wants a `.doc` file and I wrote my work in LaTeX. Is it possible to export a `.tex` format file to a `.doc` one? (Without the copy-paste method obviously)

Comment: Can you persuade your teacher to accept pdf? If not, you can try googling `pdf2doc`. You will find several free converters which may work well enough on output from `pdflatex`.

Comment: [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) can translate directly form `tex` to `doc` and for simple documents it seems to work reasonably fine.

Answer (score 6):

You could convert TeX to RTF, and then from RTF to .doc: http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/

TeX4HT can also convert to ODT, which might be a better solution, still.

Answer (score 3):

it depends to the complexity of your TeX document. If you have a lot of equations and images with subcaptions you will have a lot of trouble with your conversion. Install a trialversion of TeX2Word and try it. On the other hand it makes often more sense to convert the created pdf file into a doc format, eg by http://convertpdftoword.net/

Answer (score 2):

There are several additional ways (to post by Raphink). There is [GrindEQ](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=latex2word) (commercial), [TeX2Word](http://www.chikrii.com/) (Shareware), another [TeX2Word](http://hunyadi.info.hu/levente/en/tex2word) (free)

Comment: **PeterJansson**, I didn't find another way how to message you. Notice that edits to only correct grammar and typos are not acceptable, according to this post: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340/when-is-it-and-isnt-acceptable-to-edit