# Is possible to compile a .tex document in .doc or .docx?

Tags: compiling, latex-to-word

I'm with a really huge problem. I wrote all my thesis using LaTeX, but recently my supervisor ask me for the file for read and make some corrections in .doc or .docx

I don't know how to convert the .tex file in .doc without losing the format, the figure and tables quality, the equations.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: Before you commit to the frustrations of converting a project as large and as complicated as a thesis, you might want to ask your supervisor if they wouldn't mind making comments on the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

That is a bit of a problem. I'd look at the following resources:

- [From .tex to .doc format. Is it possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/from-tex-to-doc-format-is-it-possible)
- [Producing doc/docx from LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8836/producing-doc-docx-from-latex)
- You could also try [this website](http://www.files-conversion.com/document/latex)
- You could also take the pdf and convert that into .doc or .docx using one of many online converters

I'll keep adding resources as I find them.

Finally, you might consider going to your supervisor and pointing out that:

1. LaTeX is awesome.
2. It makes things look really nice.
3. There's this shiny [online version](http://www.sharelatex.com) where you can share documents
4. It's a great language to have a handle on.
5. Maybe you should make your edits in LaTeX!

Or, you could do as jon suggested and ask him to make comments on the pdf (printed or online).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to use the non-free Softwares. The  "Grindeq" should do the job. Also if the equations are problem Mathtype may be the help. Nevertheless, note that any conversions need a complete proof-reading.