# Convert a latex document with lots of equations and pseudocode to Microsoft Word

Tags: equations, conversion, msword, pseudocode

I have a nice latex document with a lot of mathematical equations and pseudoalgorithms. Now I need to work out this document with a colleague that can only use microsoft word. So I need to convert everything to word. I thought about using latex2html, but then I lose pseudoalgorithms and equations since they are converted as images. Could you suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: have you seen [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4145) and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/msword

Comment: could we close this as a duplicate? if not, could you highlight which issue is different :)