# Hide output, but maintain the cross-references

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, latex2rtf

I am (losing my mind) trying to convert a TeX file to a Word with [`latex2rtf`](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/). The body translates well, but the tables don't. I use a lot of cross-references and out like to maintain them.

My solution is to push the tables to the end of the document. I'd like to go further and suppress table output, but keep the cross-references. This would be one less step in my conversion process because I wouldn't have to cut the bad tables out of the Word document before appending back the good tables made outside of LaTeX.

I tried the `comment` environment from the `verbatim` package, but this doesn't work because the cross-references don't survive. Is this possible? Or should I just accept that I can't script everything? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
I would like to reference Table \ref{tab:1}, which is pushed to the end of 
the paper with a {\tt clearpage} and commented out because it doesn't convert 
correctly in {\tt latex2rtf} and I will find a solution outside of \LaTeX.

\clearpage
\begin{comment}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This table is my white whale.}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table}
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```

---

Edit: FWIW, my main problem with the tables in `latex2rtf` seems to be `ifmmode` macros, which cause frequent crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code allows you to leave the tables as-is in your document (and not push them to the end), yet obtain correct references. Well, for the labels at least. Page references, as expected, would be useless/lost, since the actual `table` is never set. However, you mention that this will be processed outside of the LaTeX environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\env@table@save@env}{}%
\providecommand{\env@table@process}{}%
\RenewEnviron{table}[1][]
{{\def\label##1{\gdef\recall@label{\label{##1}}}% Redefine \label to store label
 \renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{}% Remove caption capability
 \setbox1=\hbox{\BODY}}% Execute environment body and store it in a box
 \refstepcounter{table}\recall@label% Recall label
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
I would like to reference Table~\ref{tab:1}, which is pushed to the end of 
the paper with a \verb|clearpage| and commented out because it doesn't convert 
correctly in \verb|latex2rtf| and I will find a solution outside of \LaTeX.

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This table is my white whale.}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The approach is to redefine the floating environment and adjust the functionality of `\caption` and `\label`. The former writes stuff to the ToC/LoT (which we're not interested in) and the latter is used to reference the table. So, we nullify `\caption` and make `\label` rather store it's argument for later use. Then we manually step the `table` counter and `\recall@label` so the correct `\label` is set and can be referenced.

A similar procedure would hold for other floats. If [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) is used, there might be more work required. The same possibly goes for any other cross-reference package that might be in use.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get errors about `\subcaption`, `\ContinuedFloat`, and `\phantomcaption` called `outside of float`.

Comment: @RichardHerron: Please provide a *complete*, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your situation as an [edit to your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/133167/5764).

Comment: This is the solution as asked. I'm getting increasingly wary of complicated solutions for my own sanity. I think at this point the clearer solution is to get new coauthors.

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood something: references to tables work well in `latex2rtf`.

I make my references work using a slightly different syntax to yours, but I never require any extra packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Table~\ref{tab:widgets} blah blah: 

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\begin{tabular}{l|r}
Item & Quantity \\\hline
Widgets & 42 \\
Gadgets & 13
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Call this document *Tref.tex* or similar:

```
$> latex Tref.tex
$> latex Tref.tex
$> latex2rtf Tref.tex
```

You can then open the .rtf file in MS Word and this reference works, possibly after you hit ctrl-a and F9 (select all, update).

I think I must have missed something... Was this not what you needed?

Comment: You're right that the references work fine. But the tables come through as garbage (at least mine do, maybe because of `ifmmode`  and other macro calls) and I wanted to avoid having to manually remove them. In fact, they often crash latex2rtf. My partial solution is to wrap `tabular` environments in `verbatim` environments. Then I find the associated table and cut-and-paste.

Comment: Seems like the question then is why use `ifmode`. My solution for `latex2rtf` is to use the simplest possible source. I'm not meaning to be difficult, but the answer might be to change your approach, rather than fix this approach..?

Comment: For a *.rtf* file that includes references into a table and out of a table, please see this repository: https://github.com/AndyClifton/AccessibleMetaClass

Comment: Yes, I agree completely. After this ordeal I have pared down use of less common packages. The tables with `ifmmode` come from the Stata package [`estout`](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/index.html), which is a big part of my workflow and otherwise a godsend. `estout` also prints tables to .rtf and .csv, so I think when I come across cases like this (coauthors joining a paper later in the cycle, but that aren't LaTeX users) I'll `verbatim` out the tables, `latex2rtf` the document, and write the tables to .rtf in Stata and add them back downstream.