# LaTeX + Biblatex bibliography to other formats via Pandoc

Tags: biblatex, pandoc

I am trying to convert a simple LaTeX file that uses biblatex-chicago for citation formatting to, say, .docx via Pandoc. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to find the right invocation of Pandoc that results in a bibliography (or even the citations) included in the doc.

What I'm proposing doesn't have any complicated formulas, tables, or figures--just the bibliography. [This question's author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/how-to-convert-a-scientific-manuscript-from-latex-to-word-using-pandoc) seems to have gotten the bibliography working with Pandoc, though it appears he's maybe using straight up bibtex with maybe the natbib citation commands.

Sample LaTeX (foo.tex):

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatexmk
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article} % for a short document

% Bibliography
\usepackage[authordate,strict,bibencoding=inputenc,doi=true,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{./foo.bib}


\title{On Banality}
\author{Bob Dwyre}

\date{}

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\raggedbottom
\maketitle

People typically prefer to travel shorter distances than longer distances \parencite{zipf1946p1}. \textcite{dijkstra1959note} proposes one way of finding the shortest path.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And a sample .bib (foo.bib):

```
@article{dijkstra1959note,
    Author = {Dijkstra, Edsger W},
    Date-Added = {2014-04-28 19:35:12 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-04-28 19:35:12 +0000},
    Journal = {Numerische mathematik},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {269--271},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {A note on two problems in connexion with graphs},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {1959}}

@article{zipf1946p1,
    Author = {Zipf, George Kingsley},
    Date-Added = {2014-04-28 19:32:00 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-04-28 19:32:00 +0000},
    Journal = {American sociological review},
    Pages = {677--686},
    Publisher = {JSTOR},
    Title = {The P1 P2/D hypothesis: On the intercity movement of persons},
    Year = {1946}}
```

My invocation of Pandoc is as follows, but I see nothing related to bibliography in the final output:

```
pandoc -o foo.docx foo.tex --biblatex --bibliography=foo.bib
```

Comment: Welcome to SX Peter! I was wondering if you've already tried to get a `docx` from a markdown file? Also, it's probably irrelevant, but I would invoke the pandoc command in this case as `pandoc --biblatex --bibliography=foo.bib foo.tex -o foo.docx` (pandoc pandoc-options input-file output-file).

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tried markdown, but that's mainly because I prefer writing in LaTeX (it's a sickness, I know) and also I haven't bothered to learn the citation commands for Pandoc-flavored markdown yet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `--biblatex` option only applies when the output document is LaTeX format. When I tried `pandoc --bibliography=foo.bib -o foo.docx foo.tex` it worked for me. If you want Chicago you need to add an option for that e.g. `--csl=chicago-author-date.csl`. You can get the CSL file from [github.com/citation-style-language/styles](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles).

Comment: Excellent! It looks like I was overcomplicating it. Also +1 for the --csl=chicago-author-date.csl invocation.

Answer (score 8):

I never got this example generating any citations on my Windows 10 machine. Only after adding  `--citeproc` did the citations appear. For future reference one can try `pandoc --bibliography=foo.bib -o foo.docx foo.tex --citeproc`

Comment: This also worked for me. It seems there might have been a change since pandoc uses the citeproc library.