# Convert LaTeX to Word with Pandoc, including citations and bibliography

Tags: pandoc, latex-to-word

I'm trying to convert a LaTeX document ("latex-to-word.tex") to Word using pandoc. Unfortunately, I cannot print neither the reference list nor parenthetical citations in the Word file.

I'm running this on Mac's Terminal:

```
pandoc -s latex-to-word.tex -o latex-to-word.docx
```

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,spanish,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,url=true,backref=bibtex,bibstyle=apa,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
    @article{GrayMalins1993,
    author = {Gray, Carole and Malins, Julian},
    journal = {Principles \& Definitions: Five Papers by the European Postgraduate Art \& Design Group},
    title = {{Research Procedures/Methodology for Artists \& Designers}},
    year = {1993}
    }
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
According to \textcite{GrayMalins1993}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Any idea what else should I do to get the references in the text and at the end of the document?

Comment: You will have to explicitly specify the bibliography. See this thread for more info: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174055/

Comment: Why can't you consider `TeX4ht`?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, thanks to @ingmar I found the answer here:
[LaTeX + Biblatex bibliography to other formats via Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174055/):

The correct command should be:

```
pandoc --bibliography=bibliography.bib -o latex-to-word.docx latex-to-word.tex --citeproc
```