# Easy way for a bibliography in Word?

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, msword, latex-to-word, research

I have already tried `Mendeley` and it is difficult to add a .bib file for every research article and load it. It feels like separate research to me. Either how `Mendeley` works is clearly bad or I am doing something wrong. Is there a way to use the one master bib file from latex in `Mendeley`? It will be of massive help if I can do something similar.

I followed the instructions in the following thread
[LaTeX + Biblatex bibliography to other formats via Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174055/latex-biblatex-bibliography-to-other-formats-via-pandoc/692579#692579)
I did try the following commands

```
pandoc --bibliography=foo.bib -o foo.docx foo.tex --citeproc
```

and

```
pandoc --biblatex --bibliography=foo.bib foo.tex -o foo.docx
```

However, it only created a word document with very well crafted texts and headings. It helped me generate a list of headings. But the figures and tables were handled badly. Mainly the bibliography was empty. In fact, the references were left out even inline, meaning `\citep{authoryear}` was **not** recognized. Also, note that my articles contain lot of mathematical fonts and equations. Fewer figures and tables though, as of now. Unfortunately I could not comment on the above post because of low reputation. And also couldn't seek help.

I tried using `Python` for PDF to Word. Lots of issues there again. Is there an easy way to use the full .bib file of LaTeX for MS Word in a more elegant way? Or convert a .tex file to an equivalent Word document?

EDIT:
I tried it out. It is possible to load the complete file.bib in Mendley. Mendley reads the entire bib file and creates a list.

The only downside in Mendley is you need to select the inline references through GUI i.e., you need to select an option like "add reference" using check boxes at every in line text place you want. After that it is straight forward.

In latex you would type it. Sometimes Mendley feels better because you can search the reference through several words word : author, article name, year. So it is easier if you do not remember the author name. Because in latex you can only search with the name you gave for the bib text. Mendley works good. I did not understand it properly.

Comment: Mendeley can manually import existing bibliographies. LaTeX .bib is among the supported formats.

Answer (score 2):

If you want some document in two formats, the rule of thumb is always convert from the simpler to the complex (e.g., markdown to LaTeX), never in the opposite direction, and never ever from a complex format to another complex format. That trip always means pay a high toll.

But with respect to the references of a latex file using biblatex or bibtex this should not be a big problem. Demonstration:

1. Take the `References.bib` example of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) and name it `foo.bib`.
2. Take the last example document of [the same  answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) using biblatex  and name it `foo.tex`.
3. Run pandoc:

---

```
 pandoc -f latex  --bibliography=foo.bib -t docx foo.tex -o foo.docx
```

---

Result of `foo.docx` in LibreOffice:

[image: mwe]

As you can see, the only lost in the docx, with respect the compiled latex version, is the automatic  "References" title made with `\printbibliography,` but using:

```
\section*{References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

The title will appear in both formats:

[image: mwe2]

Comment: +1 Sounds you did the mistakes yourself in the past :). Thanks for sharing.