# pandoc convert LaTeX to docx and display "File not found in resource path"

Tags: pandoc

I am using Pandoc to convert LaTeX to docx, and the example I am using is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614855/307309.
The pandoc information as:
[image]

***But I get error：File  not found in resource path***

[image]

However, I have all of these files, so I dragged them into the terminal to ensure the correct path :
[image]

How can this be resolved? Very thanks!

---

**Sorry, I have identified the issue. Simply place the tex file in the root directory of the pandoc folder.**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch thank you very much

Comment: Please DO NOT POST images of code and logs etc, it makes it very hard to find errors. If I read the command in the picture you posted correctly, then it looks like there is a spurious space after `--bibliography=`

Comment: @DG' I have identified the issue. Simply place the tex file in the root directory of the pandoc folder. thank you!