# how to quickly convert latex to word?

Tags: math-mode, conversion, msword

I have a latex command for an equation looks like

```
$p(\mathscr{P}\mid\tilde{N})=p(\tilde{N}\mid \mathscr{P})$
```

I want to copy the equation to word 2013. I tried some tools (mathjax, LaTeX2Word-Equation, mathtype...) but the result is not so good comparison with latex output. Could you suggest to me some good tool to copy from latex command to word file. Thank all.

This is my output of three tools when I copy in word 2013

[image]

Comment: Can you please add what you want to change in the equations?  "not so good" is not a very detailed description of your problem.

Comment: Yes, As you see, the tilde and `N` are so far comparison with latex output. Note that, i want to use latex command to generate the word equation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert from Microsoft Word to a LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-can-i-convert-from-microsoft-word-to-a-latex-document)

Comment: No. K want convert math type in latex to word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a scientific manuscript from LaTeX to Word using Pandoc?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/how-to-convert-a-scientific-manuscript-from-latex-to-word-using-pandoc)

Comment: I am not sure if any of the answers in the question identified by @HenriMenke actually directly addresses the question here.

Comment: Sorry. I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thank HeneiMenke and Willie Wrong. I tried and it worked well

Answer (score 1):

I chose this `\mathscr{P}` and `\tilde{N}` by mouse in the Word generated menu (on the top of screen); do you think this is better?

By the way, why don't you think the mathjax output to be better? it seems to have inserted `\left` and `\right` into parentheses automatcally.

[image]

You seem to be very concerned with parenthesis height(?) If so, type `()` *first*, and simply paste (and do not edit inside) whatever inside which you have typed elsewhere. 
For example, you type `\tilde{N}` on another line, and type `p()`, and paste `\tilde{N}` inside `()`. 
This is because (it seems) MS Word automatically tries insert `\left` and `\right`; though not every time, the feature seem to be buggy.

Comment: Yes. It looks good. I think mathjax is not good because the mathjax's ouput has tilde is so far comparison with latex. But how you make it in word? Your result is in word, right.

Comment: my previous explaination unclear, please see I have edited.

Comment: So, your image result is from word or latex? I tried but the distance between tilde and `N` look far

Comment: The screenshot is from MS word, mine is for Mac, though; don't know whether they make difference.

Comment: Ok. Let explain my experiment to obtain the result. I copy the script `$p(\mathscr{P}\mid\tilde{N})=p(\tilde{N}\mid \mathscr{P})$` in to  https://www.mathjax.org/ site and then copy the text in the typying and choose the `LatextoWord-Equation` then paste to word. Is it correct step?

Comment: I haven't heard of the tool `LatextoWord-Equation`....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49225/discussion-between-user8430-and-aminopterin).