# how to obtain editable format

Tags: format-files

I need to obtain an editable format for my document, because I need to send (by e-mail) to someone that can edit and correct the text.
But, compling the .tex, I can obtain just .pdf, isn't it?
Or I can obtain editable format?

Comment: As you would have to correct the tex-file in the end anyway, where is the point to sent some other editable format? Sent the pdf and he/she should comment it and you then add the changes to the tex, or sent the tex-file directly.

Comment: I'm not sure he are able to add comment to pdf

Comment: This is the strength of TeX, that the documents are simple ASCII text (or UNICODE added), but there are no "embedded codes" for formatting.  Thus, you can email the `.tex` files easily, and if changes are made, a simple `diff` will immediately reveal the totality of differences that were incorporated.

Comment: If it is just for adding comments you could try to convert a format readable by MS Word (and similar) using one of the methods in, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/how-to-convert-a-scientific-manuscript-from-latex-to-word-using-pandoc.