# Can I latex2rtf beamer presentations?

Tags: beamer, latex2rtf

Can I latex2rtf beamer presentations? Is there a way around the errors?  Also is theree a good way to latexto rtf for beamer?

Comment: **Your last 10 questions have zero upvotes.** Maybe consider to work on the quality of your questions :). Here's a good start https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Maybe [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/Home) could be useful? LyX is a graphical LaTeX editor, it supports beamer documents, and if you want to share your presentation with other people that don't use LaTeX then LyX may be a user-friendly way for those people to edit the presentation.

Comment: @Marijn  Lyx also doesn't seem to work for me https://www.overleaf.com/read/mgrgdfxpkrjh    Idk why I cannot open the open office file.

Comment: @HaoS I'm not really sure what you mean. Overleaf cannot open `.rtf` files because Overleaf is a LaTeX editor and not an rtf editor. Overleaf can also not open `.lyx` files because `.lyx` files need to be opened by the LyX program. Which format do you want to convert into which other format exactly? And, more importantly, why do you want this, what is the advantage of using rtf files for you?

Comment: @Marijn   I mean't when I tried to use lyx to OpenDoc   this tex file I cannot open the resulting file.

Answer (score 2):

- From what I read in the manual I do not assume that `beamer` is supported.
- Maybe you know, that you can generate an article version of the `beamer` code. Look for `21.2 Creating Handouts Using the Article Mode` in the current `beamer` manual.
- I would use the article output for my next steps (for example `latex2rtf`, or `pandoc`, or your choise of PDF2Word converters, see [How to convert a scientific manuscript from LaTeX to Word using Pandoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/)).
- In addition, you could try the mailing list of the `latex2rtf` project: http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/support.html.

> LaTeX2RTF is known to have many bugs and many missing features. Paradoxically, this number seems to grow more and more with each day. However, we can categorically state that there are some special cases in which a LaTeX file will be translated to RTF satisfactorily by LaTeX2RTF — This was sort of disclaimer, ok? OK!

*Taken from http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net*

---

PS: **Your last 10 questions have zero upvotes.** Maybe consider to work on the quality of your questions :). Here's a good start https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.