# How can convert latex to MS word document

Tags: tables, math-mode, graphics, table-of-contents, formatting

How can I translate my Latex job into an MS Word document? I search youtube but I don't found a solution to my enquiry

Comment: [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4145/134144) and [How to convert a scientific manuscript from LaTeX to Word using Pandoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111886/134144) may be worth having a look at.

Comment: Adobe has an export pdf to .docx tool. It's not going to be perfect, though.