# Replace lstlisting with verbatim depending on a boolean

Tags: listings, conditionals, verbatim, latex2rtf

I use `latex2rtf` to convert latex documents to .rtf and thence to MS-word ([see this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)). To do this, I set up a custom class and limit which packages are used as  `latex2rtf` only accepts a limited subset of commands ([see manual pages](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/usage.html)). `latex2rtf` provides a booelan, `\iflatextortf`, that is set to true if you use `latex2rtf` as your compiler.

I now need to display code listings and maintain the `latex2rtf` functionality. That means, I want to define something in the preamble to replace calls to `\lstlisting{}` with something like `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` when `\iflatextortf` is true.

**Question:** Is it possible to use switch between the `lstlisting` and `verbatim` environment depending on the value of `\iflatextortf`, keeping the content of the environment?

The solution would not require any packages to be installed and should work with the limited subset of commands in latex2rtf ([see section 8.6.1](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/usage.html)). This should help me run compile using `latex2rtf`. Solutions using the verbatim package won't work unfortunately.

My ideal solution looks like this:

```
\newif\iflatextortf

\iflatextortf
    \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
    % whatever my replacement for lstlistings is %
\else
    \documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{report}
    \usepackage{listings}
    % something fancy with listings
    \lstnewenvironment{codeenv}[1][]{\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily}#1}{}       
\fi
```

And I would like something a little more elegant than using find & replace on the raw .tex!

Comment: Best I can tell this is impossible without the [verbatim](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) or [fancyvrb](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package, as my ideal solution _requires_ me to use verbatim within another environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion is to allow loading both [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) and [`verbatim`](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim) and use a common (new) environment to hold all your code. Under `listings`, you can define this environment using

```
\lstnewenvironment{codeenv}[1][]{}{}%
```

Using `verbatim` you can define this environment using

```
\newenvironment{codeenv}[1][]{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}%
```

Now you're able to condition on whether `listings` should be loaded using a traditional `\@ifundefined{lstlisting}{<undefined>}{<defined>}`. Here's a use case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\usepackage{verbatim}% http://ctan.org/pkg/verbatim

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{lstlisting}{% If listings is loaded
  \newenvironment{codeenv}[1][]{\verbatim}{\endverbatim}%
}{% listings is not loaded
  \lstnewenvironment{codeenv}[1][]{\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{codeenv}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
This is some verbatim text.
\end{codeenv}

\end{document}
```

Now all you have to do is wrap the

```
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
```

in your "boolean switch".

---

If the `verbatim` package is not allowed, then some code can be taken from the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) the revolves around the definition of the `verbatim` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

\makeatletter
\begingroup \catcode `|=0 \catcode `[= 1
\catcode`]=2 \catcode `\{=12 \catcode `\}=12
\catcode`\\=12 |gdef|@xverbatim#1\end{codeenv}[#1|end[codeenv]]
|endgroup
\@ifundefined{lstlisting}{
  \newcommand{\codeenv}[1][]{\@verbatim \frenchspacing\@vobeyspaces \@xverbatim}
  \def\endcodeenv{\if@newlist \leavevmode\fi\endtrivlist}
}{%
  \lstnewenvironment{codeenv}[1][]{\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{codeenv}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
This is some verbatim text.
\end{codeenv}

\end{document}
```

---

A final, fairly elementary approach might be to use the `verbatim` environment throughout your document for code examples, and redefine this environment to work as a regular listing is `listings` is loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{lstlisting}{}{%
  \let\verbatim\relax%
  \lstnewenvironment{verbatim}{\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
This is some verbatim text.
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Since `listings` does not provide `\lstrenewenvironment`, `\let`ting `\verbatim` to `\relax` frees up the `verbatim` environment for redefinition. For ease-of-use, it's best avoid making `verbatim` accept optional arguments.

Comment: This would be great except I made a mistake in my post and should have emphasized I meant the verbatim environment, not the package. The version of the listing that I use with latex2rtf should be generated using as few packages as possible (preferably none) to make it compatible with latex2rtf. Unfortunately verbatim is not compatible.

Comment: @LostBrit: I've updated the code to remove the verbatim package requirement.

Comment: Apparently `\catcode` doesn't work with Latex2rtf either ([see documentation](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/usage.html)). Latex2rtf includes the boolean, `\iflatextortf`. Ideally, I would just define `codeenv` as you suggest, and replace `lstlisting` with `verbatim` if `\iflatextortf` were true , but AFAIK, you can't use verbatim as the input to an environment.

Comment: @LostBrit: I've dumbed it down even further. See if the last addition works for you.

Comment: This works really well. Accepted, thank you!

Comment: OK, now there's an extra line at the start of text produced with final approach to the verbatim environment. Any ideas?

Comment: @AndyClifton: With [this code](http://pastebin.com/pbZXkkYU) I get [this (expected) output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRQNA.png). What do you mean by "an extra line at the start of text"?