# Converting LaTeX file into RTF - can't seem to detect class file?

Tags: conversion, resume, latex2rtf

I have a resume in LaTeX format, that's using the Resume class from Michael DeCorte.

I'm trying to convert it to RTF format, and hitting some issues.

```
$ latex2rtf resume
resume.tex:3    Document format <resume> unknown, using article format
resume.tex:3   Package/option 'margin' unknown.
resume.tex:3   Package/option 'line' unknown.
resume.tex:7   Unknown command '\name'
resume.tex:8   Error! Could not find <\end{resume}>
```

The resume.cls file is in the current directory, however latex2rtf can't seem to find it?

Is there some way of getting this to work? Or another way to output the LaTeX file to RTF/Word .doc?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: [LaTeX2RTF](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/) has problems: "There are drawbacks to the conversion process. In fact, don't expect any LaTeX file to be converted as you would like, don't expect it to be converted without errors or warnings, and don't be especially surprised when it doesn't convert at all. LaTeX2RTF is known to have many bugs and many missing features. Paradoxically, this number seems to grow more and more with each day. However, we can categorically state that there are some special cases in which a LaTeX file will be translated to RTF satisfactorily by LaTeX2RTF."

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way: you can use a LaTeX-to-HTML converter. MS Word can open and edit the result HTML file directly. Then, just save it as a .doc, .docx or .rtf

EDIT (10/22/2013): after looking older answers on the same topic, it seems that [TeX4ht](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html) is a good choice to the TeX-to-HTML or XHTML conversion. It also converts to OpenDocument format (which is used by the Apache OpenOffice suite).
If you have MS Office 2010, [it can open OpenDocument texts directly](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-word-to-open-or-save-a-document-in-the-opendocument-text-odt-format-HA010355766.aspx).

See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format) for more details.

Comment: conversion to HTML results in almost completely unformatted text, like a webpage that has failed to find its stylesheet and fallen back to raw html mode.