# Will a recipient need Bibtex4Word if I use it in my Word Doc

Tags: bibtex, msword

LaTex is my choice for creating documents or presentations. I hate using anything else

However I need to do something in Word format. For reasons beyond my control, it is the only format accepted for what I need to do. It will be a few thousand pages long and I need to cite a lot of sources and also have a bibliography. I have never really used Word to be honest.

I googled and there is apparently a plugin called Bibtex4Word. If I use this to create citations and a bibliography, can I then send the Word Doc to someone who doesn't have that plugin installed? In other words, can I process the tex and then convert it to normal Word text (If that question makes sense).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format) helps.

Comment: I strongly suggest you test if a good sample of your huge document in rmarkdown or bookdown  format (using  RStudio) produce a Word document enough good for your needs.  Conversion among  complex formats (e.g. LaTeX to Word or Word to LaTeX) is often  a nightmare, but markdown is designed for a simple to complex conversion workflow that usually works. As bonus point, in any moment you can obtain also a  HTML, LaTeX, or PDF versions at the same cost.

Comment: Cf. [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621417/34551) too. I believe you will be fine using pandoc :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work fine. Bibtex4word just adds text into your word document. If you send it to someone else they can view, print or edit the document as normal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!