# How to convert LaTex to word using PanDoc and keep citations as numeral

Tags: bibliographies, citing, pandoc

I use **Pandoc** to convert a `tex` file to `docx`. I used the following command

```
pandoc -s foo.tex --bibliography=foo.bib -o foo.docx
```

But in the output word document, citation are in format of `(author date)`, while I want just a number like `[1]`.

Comment: `Pandoc` can use any CSL file to format your citations. Please check out the [Zotero style repo](https://www.zotero.org/styles) and download a matching style.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution is to use a CSL file to format the citations. I used `ieee.csl` from https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles

```
pandoc -s foo.tex --bibliography=foo.bib --csl=ieee.csl -o foo.docx
```

Comment: Sorry this is not at least working for a standard article with a plain bibliography