# Latex to MS word

Tags: bibtex, conversion, msword

There is tool called GrindEq for converting Latex document into MS word format, it work good if references are added using "Bibitem", but if references are inserted using "Bibtex" database, then references do not appear in MS word format.
How can we proceed with conversion Latex to MS word if references in Latex document are added using bibtex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)

Comment: @RomainPicot I fail to see how this question about a particular tool is a duplicate of a very generic question on the topic.

Comment: @yo' The last question from the OP say, for me, how can I do this but did not ask for using GrindEq especially I think

Comment: But then we may say that OP is asking specifically about bibliography. It feels like "OK, I do not care about the rest of the document now... but you must help me insert the bibliography." A general question with the first answer saying "If I were you I would not do that" is not an appropriate reference.

Comment: It is just one hour anyway.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

I don't have GrindEq nor MS Word, but in the compilation of your TeX document a `.bbl` file is created (after the typical *compile-a-few-times* steps). This is actually the file which BibTeX converted the database into properly formatted `\bibitem`s.

You can make a copy of your TeX file, and in this copy, instead of using the line `\bibliography{...}`, copy paste the contents of the `.bbl` file. This way, the new file contains the `\bibitem`s directly, so it is independent of BibTeX.

Comment: Did some shuffling (rollback if you dare! :P )