# Is there a way to produce \cite{xx} as it is in the generated PDF file?

Tags: macros, citing, msword, proofreading

My thesis is written in many tex files and I would like to have it proofread. However, the proof reader is requesting the thesis in MS Word format.

Although the generated PDF can easily be converted into the requested format, the citations will be replaced by numbers instead of the `\cite{xx}` in the raw tex document.

Is there a way to keep and produce `\cite{xx}` as it is in the generated PDF file?

**EDIT:** I am not asking about how to convert latex documents into MS Word. I am already able to do that. I am asking about **how to keep and produce `\cite{xx}` as it is in the generated PDF file?**

Comment: Could they proofread it in PDF format?

Comment: You didn't ask this, but my guess is you're also interested in seeing the accompanying bibkeys to cross-reference. Why not just use the [`showkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) package?

Comment: @andrewCashner no, the proof reader I am interested in accepts only word documents. If I could do what I am asking about, it will be an easy job: simply copy and paste the proofread sentences back to tex files.

Comment: @werner If I can change the options so it produces '\cite{}' and not only the keys, it will be exactly what I am looking for! Otherwise, I would need to add '\cite{}' around each single reference key in the proofread sentences, which will be a HUGE task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latex to MS word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287741/latex-to-ms-word)

Comment: @WYSIWYG no it is not. Please read my question and comments carefully.

Comment: @PatternRecognition: Okay, so *all* you want is for `\cite{xx}` to be written *as-is* in the text, and that's that? Do you have multiple bibliographies? What bibliography package are you using?

Comment: @Werner I do not know :) I am using CambridgeLaTeXTemplate thesis template and my reference are store in a bibtex file. I aslo use    \bibliographystyle{apalike}. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: You could just paste your TeX source code into a Word document, if you really want to preserve all the commands *and* allow the proofreader to use Word's editing and commenting features.

Comment: That is difficult as I would need to remove commented lines, which are between almost every two paragraphs. Anyway, since I do not have too many figures and tables, I am going to deal with their references manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro,natbib}

\AtEndDocument{\nocite{*}}% Include all references
\LetLtxMacro\oldcite\cite
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{o m}{%
  {\ttfamily\string\cite\string{\detokenize{#2}\string}}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abc,
  title = {Title - ABC},
  author = {A Author and B Author and C Author},
  journal = {Journal ABC},
  year = {1234}}
@article{def,
  title = {Title - DEF},
  author = {D Author and E Author and F Author},
  journal = {Journal DEF},
  year = {5678}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

As can be seen in~\cite{abc}, we use~\cite[p.\ 5]{def}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The above assumes you're only using `\cite` for citations. The call to `\nocite{*}` also assumes that you'll be including *all* citations in your bibliography file as part of your bibliography.

You can change the format from `\ttfamily` to something else, if needed. It's purely meant to distinguish code from actual document content.

Comment: To not change the layout, one could use the original cite, and put the detokenized source in a zero-width box in footnote position or slightly above the produced citation.

Comment: @jfbu: Yes. Placing it just above the original `\cite` would be similar to what is provided by [`showkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please show how I can do the same with \textit{} \ref{} ?

Comment: @PatternRecognition: What does `\textit` have to do with it?

Comment: @Werner I just wanted to preserve the italicization of words after copying the proof read back to latex. It is not, however, as important as \ref{}. Thank you again for your responses.

Answer (score 4):

You could redefine the `\cite` command so that it prints itself instead of the citation:

```
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\textbackslash cite\{#1\}}}
```