# Displaying a (set of) control sequences in verbatim

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, verbatim, msword

I want to have some code (or package, or documentclass) that I can put in the header of the Latex document so that when compiling it reads certain commands in verbatim.

For example: all cross references like `\cref` `\eqref` etc should be displayed in verbatim if I turn that code on, but if I remove it, I compile the document including these control sequences. Ideally that would work for the inline math environment, too.

It feels like their must be an easy way to do, yet I am unable to find it.

**UPDATE:** For lack of a better solution after 2.5 years, I posted my workaround as an answer.

*Some background:* I want to hand the paper to someone that operates in MS Word. If she suggests changes (using MS Word track cahnges), I want to copy paste entire paragraphs back into the latex file. I am aware that Latex/Word compatibility is not the best, but there is no other way.

I am looking for an efficient way to get comments on the text into latex without losing crossreferences or control sequence from the copy-pasting exercise.

My workaround so far is flagging all in line commands putting `\$` in front of it and then replacing them one by one afterwards. But that seems ineffecient.

Comment: It sounds like you want to `\string` everything when in proof mode, and not when in final mode: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\prm}{\string}%proof
%\newcommand{\prm}{}%final
\begin{document}
\prm\part{Part Title}
\prm\section{Section Text}
\end{document}`. Detokenizing the whole document is possible but loses formatting (lines, paragraphs, ..), so not practical.

Comment: @Cicada: I was playing around with this, it is close to, but not yet ideal. Ideally, I would get `\section{Section Text}` as the output. Instead I get `sectionSection Text`.

The closest I got so far was using the `\renewcommand{\command}[1]{\textbackslash command\{#1\}}` option. Yet there I have two problems:

1. if there are optional arguments (more than 1 in particular) it seems to get messed up.
2. if I had e.g. `\section{section_text}` I cannot get around the math interpretation of `section_text`

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: The on-off switch-nature of the task implies a grouping, which in turn implies a 'bracketing', either hard-coded per command, or a loop identifying the command (from \ to final }. Hard-coded wrapper example: `\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifprm
\prmtrue
\newcommand{\prm}{\string}%proof
\newcommand\verbit[1]{\ifprm\detokenize{#1}\else#1\fi}
\begin{document}
\catcode`{=12\catcode`}=12\relax\prm\part{Part Title}\catcode`{=1\catcode`}=2

\verb+\section{Text 1}+

\detokenize{\section{Text 2}}

\verbit{\section{Text 3}}

\prmfalse\verbit{\section{Text 3a}}\end{document}`

Comment: Getting a tick to display as a tick is a bit tricky: `\catcode``{=12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that no other answer appeared, I think it is ok, to use my workaround thanks to the hints by [@Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada) as the best approximation of an answer:

I have been able to achieve a workaround using ideas from here: [Is there a way to produce `\cite{xx}` as it is in the generated PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294282/is-there-a-way-to-produce-citexx-as-it-is-in-the-generated-pdf-file). I have a `proofread.sty` that looks like this

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \catcode`_=12
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
  \mathcode`_="8000
}
\usepackage{twoopt}
\renewcommand{\foo}[1]{\textbackslash foo\{#1\}}
\renewcommand{\footwoopt}[3][\empty][\empty]{\textbackslash foo[#1][#2]\{#3\}}
```

for all command foo that I have. The first part solves problems with entering math mode if there are underscores in labels. (see [Underscore in textmode vs mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62705/underscore-in-textmode-vs-mathmode))

The [`twoopt`](https://ctan.org/pkg/twoopt?lang=en) package and the associated control `\footwoopt` deals with potential optional arguments.

I am not entirely happy with this solution (since I still have to redefine all handles, the math thing is annoying, and I am afraid it is not very robust), but for now, that works.