# Using LaTeX -- dealing with reviewers

Tags: pdftex, compiling, msword

Regarding students who use LaTeX for writing the thesis or paper. Is there any solution for Generating only `.pdf` version using LaTeX, as the reviewers I am dealing with are not using LaTeX and I have to convert every `.pdf` generated in LaTeX to Word to make it easy for them to review and edit it.

is there any way make this process easier?????

Comment: PDF is the primary output formats of **pdf**LaTeX... so, if you're using that, then there should be no question. But other than that, you can use LaTeX (which generates a PS) and then convert to PDF.

Comment: I don't understand your question -- you ask how to generate a `.pdf` version  only and then you say you have to convert the `.pdf` to Word, so you have the `.pdf` file then already?

Comment: This is not “primarily opinion-based”. It's a common question that users would have; we should search for duplicates with useful answers.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The question was (wrongly) edited away from its original and confusing meaning ... Now it is totally reversed

Comment: Example duplicate question: [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format?noredirect=1&lq=1) or maybe one of the questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collaboration?sort=votes&pageSize=50), though I think the answer today is to use ShareLaTeX or Overleaf, if possible.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Good point, rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and the best solution that worked for me is as follows: 
1. Extract figures as images.
2. Convert latex to html. There are many ways to do (this converts the .tex to .html) 
3. Copy and paste to word.

I tried the following technique too but didnt work well fir me.
- Adobe acrobat pro for converting pdf to docx or any other converter. 
This converts the pdf to word. But many times there are many errors in the layout, and unreable/editable text. And creating way too many textboxes which makes it so hard to edit. I suggest trying this first.

Comment: Ok! I just tried the acrobat reader website.. The result is perfect for the whole these ... everything as the pdf one.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Cost some money, but it is reasonable (:

Comment: There are free stuff too with similar quality. Check this https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/free-tools-convert-pdf-to-word-windows-mac-linux/