# Docx to Docx via Pandoc with the constraint of complex formats

Tags: formatting, conversion, msword, markdown

I am looking for a workflow to enable 'only Word' people to keep working with their favorite editor while:

- enabling developpers to use `markdown`
- use a robust saving format managable with `Git`
- prevent template breaks

So the idea is :

```
docx --> MD | LaTeX --> docx
```

This looks right and there are many posts here explaining how to do it with `Pandoc` in both directions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format).

But when it comes to complex formating like here:

[image]

How to manage it ? There is no complex types in `word`.

I would like the `MD` code to look as this pseudo code:

```
## Interconnection
**Rule RRR-1.01** : it is $MANDATORY to .....
$Precision
  * It is .....
  * It is necessary to .....
  * One shall .....
```

- `$MANDATORY` would be a kind of macro or type name defined to write 'MANDATORY' in bold and blue color
- `$Precision` would be replaced by a `HTML` definition providing the frame, the icon, etc, and embedding what is indented underneeth.

As far as I know, `MD` does not support macro definitions, and the [`Pandoc extended MD`](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown) does not include such complex formating capabilities, unless by using raw html insertion, what is forbidden for my sweet users.

`LaTeX` instead of MD would be acceptable for non developper people, provided they don't have to know anything about it (developper people would use only `MD --> pdf | docx` and no complex formatting). Even a solution like `LyX` won't be adopted.

I would like to stick to `MD` and avoid `LaTeX` if possible to avoid too much training. The solution should work both from `docx` to `MD` and from `MD` to `docx`.

Comment: How is this related to LaTeX? Is LaTeX even used in MD to docx conversion?

Comment: Not directly unless there is no other solution. Besides, there are many posts regarding `Pandoc` here. It looks the best stack for it.

Comment: If it is never using LaTeX in any of its steps (I don't think it does for docx convertion), then I don't think this is the right place to ask. Not sure where else though. Pandoc is often mentioned here as the pandoc to PDF seems to go over latex.

Comment: Q) Word >PanDoc > LaTeX > PanDoc > Word  A) allowed i.e. Body=TeX

Comment: If I can fully avoid most users to know about LaTeX, then it is fully acceptable. Developpers can do it differently since they just need :  `MD --> PDF`. But that mean a process that can translate a word document to LaTeX with complex formating. I am not sure I can find something off-the-shelves. Probably I will need a VBA macro in between to deal with complex formating. So I edit the OP

Comment: Converting from doc to something for storing and back to doc for working? You (your documents) will get lost in translation.

Comment: `Asciidoc` looks nice too, cf [this](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/asciidoc.txt) how [NOTE] is rendered like [this](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/asciidoc.css-embedded.html). `Asciidoctor` in addition as a macro feature which may be usefull