# How to convert from LaTeX to Word on Mac?

Tags: thesis, latex-to-word, convert

I wrote my thesis with LaTeX on Overleaf, but my supervisor wants a Word-file of it. The thesis consists of multiple .tex-documents which are are linked to a central main.tex document. I found some tips for doing this, but they only work at Microsoft-computers. How could I convert from LaTeX to Word on a Macbook?

Comment: You could try looking through the suggestions on https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4145/226. Some are web-based, and process the PDF instead of the LaTeX source files.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a recent version of MS Word (2013, 2016, 2019), compile you thesis into a PDF, but switch off letter spacing, small caps and hyphenation. Also, deactivate `microtype`. Open the PDF in Word. The conversion is pretty good.

It may be an idea to use a mono spaced font for export, and change it back to something more readable in Word.

Answer (score 2):

Pandoc (https://pandoc.org/) converts latex to a lot of different formats and allows conversion from tex to docx.

There are installers for macOS and also the source if you want to build it yourself.