# How to convert from Latex to Word properly?

Tags: convert, latex-to-word

I have a latex document on Overleaf that contains equations and mathematical symbols and I want to convert my document to the Word version, I transformed my .tex document to .pdf then I used an online converter for pdf to Word, but all the equations get ruined.

Is there a way to do the conversion without damaging the equations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org)
the simples usage is like this `pandoc -o file.docx file.tex`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to install pandoc?

Comment: @walid Read [Getting started with pandoc: Step 1: Install pandoc](https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html)

Comment: I believe pandoc only does equations by converting to images. This is fine as long as you don't want to edit the equations in Word.

Comment: @pml is this command `pandoc -o file.docx file.tex` work even if my latex has figures?

Comment: @MarkVerschell Verschell do you recommend another way si I  can edit the equations?

Comment: @walid I believe, you really should try!

Comment: @pml yes I tried but each time an error pop up regarding my latex! Is there a way to skip them and do the conversion anyway?

Comment: Pandoc converts tex math to editable word equations, not images.

Answer (score 3):

Equations are where you are going to experience your biggest problem. (One could also ask WHY you want to do this, as you will have a much richer experience with LaTeX, but I won't ask).

Since Word supposedly understands MathML, perhaps your best option would be to first use [tex4ht](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html) or [LaTeXML](https://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML/) to convert to HTML with MathML and then import that file into Word.

Comment: you can convert to word directly with TeX4ht, using `make4ht -f odt filename.tex` command. This has advantages over the HTML export, like support for footnotes and similar features that are supported by Word, but not by HTML.

Comment: How can I use tex4ht?

Comment: @walid it is installed automatically when you have a local TeX installation. You can then use [make4ht](https://www.kodymirus.cz/make4ht/make4ht-doc.html) on the command line.

Comment: @michal.h21 I am using Overleaf. Is it possible to install a Tex in my laptop (which one)?

Comment: @walid it is possible to use make4ht with Overleaf, but it is not that easy: https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html It is best to use TeX Live, as it is most up to date.