# Tool for converting \cite and other crossrefs to plain text

Tags: cross-referencing, conversion, msword, latex-to-word

An article of mine is going to be published in a journal that, unfortunately, does not accept LaTeX as a format, so I need to provide the text in Word or OpenOffice format. As a preliminary step to a full conversion, I want to convert all cross references, including citations, to plain text.

I am looking for a parser to **replace in the .tex file** all cross references and citations with the corresponding plain text. For example: `\eqref{eq:first}` should become "(3)", and `\citep{marx-engels}` should become "(Marx and Engels, 1948)" according to the proper bibliographic style, and so on.

Packages like `tex4ht` are two sophisticated in this regard, as they try to keep the cross reference, which I do not need.

Comment: You can generate your final document en LaTeX then open the pdf with MS Word (I am using 2013). You will be surprised!. Then save it as .docx

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to generate a word file out of a LaTeX document, it is an easier way. You can go from LaTeX > pdf > word.

Using this code a produced a document with formulas, a figure and references taken from `biblatex-examples.bib`, using `biblatex` with APA style.

I suppressed the page number and the headers.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
style=APA,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname37.bib}
    % examples form biblatex-examples.bib
@article{sarfraz,
    author       = {M. Sarfraz and M. F. A. Razzak},
    title        = {Technical section: {An} algorithm for automatic capturing of
        the font outlines},
    year         = 2002,
    volume       = 26,
    number       = 5,
    pages        = {795-804},
    issn         = {0097-8493},
    journal      = {Computers and Graphics},
}

    @article{bertram,
        author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
        title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces},
        journaltitle = {JAMS},
        date         = 1996,
        volume       = 9,
        number       = 2,
        pages        = {529-571},
        langid       = {english},
        langidopts   = {variant=american},
        shorttitle   = {Gromov invariants},
    }

@book{kullback,
    author       = {Kullback, Solomon},
    title        = {Information Theory and Statistics},
    year         = 1959,
    publisher    = {John Wiley \& Sons},
    location     = {New York},
}

    
@online{markey,
    author       = {Markey, Nicolas},
    title        = {Tame the {BeaST}},
    date         = {2005-10-16},
    url          = {http://mirror.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf},
    subtitle     = {The {B} to {X} of {BibTeX}},
    version      = {1.3},
    urldate      = {2006-10-01},
    langid       = {english},
    langidopts   = {variant=american},
    sorttitle    = {Tame the Beast},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname37.bib}

\begin{document}    

\blindmathpaper
    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Grid 100 x 100}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\end{figure}

From \citep{sarfraz}.  See also \citep{bertram} and \citep{kullback} and \cite{markey}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the look of the pdf with Sumatra viewer.

[image: s]

Opening the same file with ms word (I am using 2013) you get

[image: w]

where I did some yellow marking. The formulas will appear as figures, exactly as seen in the LaTeX generated pdf.

You can now add the footer and header as required, using ms word tools.

See other alternatives here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551411/161015