# Pandoc: Latex to Word with Equation References

Tags: pdftex, pandoc, msword, latex-to-word

Please consider the very simple latex file below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
 \label{eq:somelabel}
   e=mc^2
\end{equation}

The equation \ref{eq:somelabel} is a typical formula.


\end{document}
```

which is saved as test_latex.tex. When I try to convert this to a word document with

```
pandoc test_latex.tex -o -s test_word.docx
```

in the test_word.docx file the reference to the equation is not correct (instead of a number I see the label).

How can I fix this?
Many thanks!

Comment: You might be out of luck: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2851

Comment: `make4ht -f odt test_latex` compiles your file correctly. It creates ODT, not DOCX, but Word can open it too.

Comment: I wonder if this https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-eqnos can help or it requires me to start from a markdown file....

Comment: `pandoc-eqnos` will need markdown input. Give `make4ht` a try!

Comment: Yes, I will give make4ht a try, but I need to master also pandoc because it has a much wider scope in the type of docs it can handle. The cross reference section here https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-convert-files-from-latex-to-ms-word-using-pandoc/  may be what I need.

Comment: Pandoc is great and you can do a lot with `pandoc-crossref` and other filters, but you need to write in markdown to make the most of it

Answer (score 2):

This is my work around:

1. Convert LaTeX document to epub3 document with MathML by using [tex4ebook](https://ctan.org/pkg/tex4ebook) utility: `tex4ebook -f epub3 test_latex.tex "mathml"`
2. Convert this output to MS Word document by using Pandoc: `pandoc test_latex.epub -o test_latex.docx`

Note that you might need to revise your LaTeX source file before feeding it to tex4ebook, this utility is very fragile and expects a very simple LaTeX document (i.e. documents that use only basic packages). If you get some error messages, you should try with a small fraction of your LaTeX document and detect the reason of the error (error messages produced by tex4ebook does not help at all). In my case I removed some packages like enumitem, tikz, fancyhdr, etc.. I have also figured out that labels and references including **colons** like `\label{eq:chap1-eq1}` cause error, so i changed them as `\label{eq-chap1-eq1}` you should detect all issues like this by trying small fractions of your document.

I have managed to convert large documents like a whole book with this method.