# How to Convert Latex to Word Document?

Tags: convert

I think this is the question that a lot of people are looking for, how to convert from latex to word in the most optimal way, without having to use the pdf convert tool. Thanks for all the replies

Comment: Have you checked the previous answers? There is no silver bullet.

Comment: ... or at least nobody have *implemented* such a thing that can handle every cases yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to convert from `TeX` 2 `Word`, I've mentioned some below (upto my knowledge...)

1. Chikri ([www.chikrii.com](http://www.chikrii.com))
2. Pandoc
3. GrindEq

You can refer [Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format) for better understanding...