# Avoid eps to png conversion using mk4ht oolatex

Tags: conversion, eps, tex4ht, png, open-office

I have a big set of `eps` images and I need to place them into an `OpenOffice` (`odt`) document. I wrote a simple script that creates a `tex` file containing these `eps` images and now I'm trying to convert it to `odt` format with:

```
mk4ht oolatex eps-images.tex
```

The problem is that all the images are converted to `png` format, thus becoming (ugly) bitmaps instead of (nice) vector images.

Reading the manpage of `mk4ht`, I see that there is an option to skip image conversion:

```
-p     Do not convert pictures
```

but this option doesn't apply directly to `mk4ht` but has to be passed to one of its sub-scripts: `t4ht`.

Looking at the conversion process with `ps afxu` (under Linux), the sequence of nested commands is:

```
\_ /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/mk4ht oolatex eps-images.tex
   \_ sh -c /usr/share/tex4ht/htlatex eps-images.tex "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-cooxtpipes -coo"
       \_ /bin/sh /usr/share/tex4ht/htlatex eps-images.tex xhtml,ooffice ooffice/! -cmozhtf -cooxtpipes -coo
           \_ t4ht -f/eps-images.tex -cooxtpipes -coo
               \_ sh -c dvipng -T tight -x 1400 -D 72 -bg Transparent -pp 40:40 eps-images.idv -o eps-images19x.png
                   \_ dvipng -T tight -x 1400 -D 72 -bg Transparent -pp 40:40 eps-images.idv -o eps-images19x.png
```

So the question is: how can I get a `-p` option down there to `t4ht`?

**EDIT1: Thanks to [CV Radhakrishnan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18704/cv-radhakrishnan) for [its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75359/19518)! We're getting closer, but it still doesn't work.**

If I run the command:

```
mk4ht oolatex eps-images ' '  ' '  ' -p'
```

starting from scratch, only with `tex` files in the main folder, the output of the last two scripts is:

```
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2009-01-31-07:33 kpathsea)
tex4ht -f/eps-images 
  -i/usr/share/texmf/tex4ht/ht-fonts/ 
  ooffice/! 
  -cmozhtf 
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `ooffice/!.dvi'
--- error --- Can't find/open file `ooffice/!.dvi'
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2009-01-31-07:34 kpathsea)
t4ht -f/eps-images 
  -p 
  -cooxtpipes 
  -coo 
(/usr/share/texmf/tex4ht/tex4ht.env)
--- warning --- Can't find/open file `eps-images.lg'
```

and no `odt` file is created. So the `-p` option actually reaches the `t4ht` command, but something in the middle is still missing and the script doesn't complete.

Conversely, if I first run:

```
mk4ht oolatex eps-images
```

thus creating all the `png` images, and then run:

```
mk4ht oolatex eps-images ' '  ' '  ' -p'
```

all the `png` images are embedded into the final `odt` file (that is corrupt, however). So, it seems that someone in the middle still uses/needs the `png` images.

**EDIT2: found another small hint [here](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn5.html#QQ1-5-27).**

```
Conditional bitmap conversion for imported graphic files

Q. How to avoid the conversion of eps files to PNG’s, included through the \includegraphics{...} command’, each time the source file is run across tex4ht.

Compile your source with the command line ‘ htlatex filename "html,info" ’, and check the log file for the information provided there. In particular, the ‘\Configure{graphics*} {wmf} ...’ example may be adapted for dealing with eps files, where a conditional conversion is requested within the ‘\Needs{"..."}’ command (possibly indirectly through a call to a script for doing he job).
```

### Can someone improve this solution?

Comment: See [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87020/8057) for a hint on how to achieve what you want. I'm still curious which vector format and which conversion utility you intend to use -- I couldn't get to work neither of PDF, SVG or EPS. Please share your experience!

Comment: I was just trying to avoid the PNG conversion. I had EPS files at the beginning and I was trying to build a ODT file with EPS files within. Unfortunately I didn't manage to reach this goal and I've given up. As soon as I have some spare time I'll give a try to your method, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for `mk4ht` is as given below:

```
mk4ht command file option1 option2 option3
```

`command` could be `htlatex` or `mzlatex` or `oolatex` of any one of the scripts provided by `tex4ht`.

`option1` is passed on to `tex4ht.sty` (like `html`, `xhtml`, `mathml` ...)

`option2` is passed on to `tex4ht.env` and `tex4ht` binary, the post-processor of `*.dvi` output.

`option3` is those which are passed on to `t4ht` binary which creates images, css and executes shell specific stuff.

So your command will be:

```
mk4ht oolatex eps-images ' '  ' '  ' -p'
```

Please take care of the space before `-p` which is important.

Answer (score 2):

I have an improvement to the answer - but still not the perfect solution probably.

I have used the configuration approach of krlmlr suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46156/pdf-image-files-and-htlatex/87020#87020) and it worked.:

(It is also probably the same thing suggested by your "hint")

I just wrote a **configuration file**, called my.cfg:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
       \Configure{graphics*}
         {eps}
         {
          \Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.eps}
         }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Then I ran

```
mk4ht oolatex test "my" " " " -p"
```

I got a test.odt file with the .eps image embedded, without conversion.

The only problem is that the image looked very small, as width and height were not specified.
I looked at the content.xml file inside test.odt (which is just a .zip file really).

In the content.xml file, the lines which draw the image looked like this:

```
<text:section
 text:name="fig" text:style-name="Figure"><text:p text:style-name="bigskip"/>


<!--l. 9
--><text:p text:style-name="Text-body"> <draw:frame draw:name="prova.eps" text:anchor-type="as-char" draw:z-index="0"><draw:image xlink:href="Pictures/prova.eps" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad"/><!--draw:name="pict"  

--></draw:frame>&#xD;
</text:p>
```

which is different compared to what you get when you let it convert the image:

```
<text:section
 text:name="fig" text:style-name="Figure"><text:p text:style-name="bigskip"/>


<!--l. 9
--><text:p text:style-name="Text-body"><draw:frame draw:name="test0x.png" text:anchor-type="as-char" draw:z-index="0" svg:width="411pt" svg:height="195pt"><draw:image xlink:href="Pictures/test0x.png" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad"/><!--draw:name="  " 
--></draw:frame><!--tex4ht:graphics  
name="test0x.png" src="prova.eps" svg:width="411.03561pt" svg:height="195.22935pt"  

-->&#xD;
</text:p>
```

Also, I've noticed that when including the unconverted eps image, you get a long pause when you first open the document and the zoom function also works very slowly.

So maybe it's not a good idea to embed .eps images into .odt.

I also noticed that when you manually create an .odt file and insert an eps image, the zoom works smoothly - but if you close the document and re-open it, then you get a long loading at the start and the zoom stutters.
So this is probably an OpenOffice problem and not something related to the way we insert eps images via tex4ht.

Anyway, besides performance problems, the problem which still awaits a solution is: how do we get eps images into .odt with proper size (width/height)?

**However, the main question is answered: use a configuration file and the -p option.**

---

**ADDENDUM (on why -p doesn't work you):**
Notice that I used " " instead of ' ' in the mk4ht command.
Using ' ' actually gave me an error (different from yours).
Also, I notice in your output tex4ht -f/eps-images 
Why that instead of tex4ht eps-images ?